# What's missing from this strategy of choosing which C# collection to use?

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, conceptual

Here's my strategy for choosing which C# collection type to use:

- if number of items in collection is fixed, then use an **array**, e.g.:

  string[] directions = new string[] { "north", "south", "east", "west" };
- otherwise always use `List<T>`
- unless of course you need a more specialized collection, e.g. `Stack<T>, Queue<T>, or Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
- but never use ArrayList anymore

**Based on your experience, what is missing from this strategy?**

Comment: Not overly sure why this is community wiki?

Comment: I thought it was good etiquette to mark opinion questions as community wiki. There really isn't a specific answer to this question, I just to want put my strategy out there and see based on experience of others, if there is anything missing that I should know.

Comment: My take on it is that if there are demonstrably wrong answers, it doesn't belong as community wiki.

Comment: sadly, it is not possible to undo a community wiki: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/ability-to-undo-the-community-wiki

Comment: I pretty much never use arrays (`T[]`) - `List<T>` is my default even for fixed size collections.

Answer (score 7):

Your rules work fine.

In addition:

- Always perfer generic (or specialized) collections over ungeneric (`object`-based) ones.
- Use `HashSet<T>` if you want to check for mere existence instead of key-value-mappings (which is represented through `Dictionary`).
- In case of dictionaries, consider the use of ordered maps (`SortedList<...>`, `SortedDictionary<...>`) if ordering seems important.
- Use linked lists if you have remove/insert operations in the middle.

and of course the most important one:

- Never export concrete collection types: Always use the most general interface, which is - in the most cases - `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that in the majority of cases, even if I knew the number of items in a collection, I'd use List, simply for the number of utility functions it provides and compatibility with LINQ.

Hashmaps are an important use case, for when you would want faster access to items within the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Collection<T>` if you plan to override add/remove/clear methods in an inherited class because there are virtual methods.